# How could @Autowire to a interface work without the implementation of the interface?

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I am a beginning learning the spring framework. In part of the code, a controller @Autowired to a interface named IXYZMapper which have no implemented class of it. But it have a corresponding Mybatis mapper file named XYZMapper.xml. Inside the xml mapper file, it have the following information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >
<mapper namespace="IXYZMapper">
  <select>
    ....
  </select>
  ...
</mapper>
```

So does that means the spring or mybatis would automatically create a class to implement the IXYZMapper, then the the ApplicationContext would register a instance of it as a bean. Later no matter what @Autowired to the Interface, it return the automatically generated bean?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with MyBatis, but that is exactly how Spring Data repositories work: The class implementing the interface is created at runtime as a JDK proxy. (An alternative, seen in MapStruct, is that the tool creates Java code at compile-time and compiles it normally.)

Comment: @chrylis mybatis works the way you described.